# Disable Google Calendar desktop notifications

Tags: notifications, google-calendar

I have turnd *Notifications* to `Off` on the *Calendar | Settings*:

[image]

But desktop popup notifications were still occurring:

[image]

Even after *completely shutting down chrome and restarting* these notifications are being displayed. So then what else needs to be done?

I am on `macOS Catalina`

Comment: Are you using Windows or Mac?

Comment: @Vdub ya I neglected that critical info: `catalina`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "System Preferences" then "Notifications" scroll down to "Google Chrome" and turn off alerts.

Comment: actually the one I wanted was to turn off Calendar notifications. But this was helpful to find the right place to go

Comment: Oh, gotcha I didn't know you were using Apple calendar I thought it was from google calendar. Glad you got it fixed.

Comment: I am using google calendar : the point is that I had not known where to find the google calendar specific setting: from your answer I ended up finding it. You might make a tweak to the answer to explain it ;)